# Laravel - Store new record in database through API

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to create a new record in my database through the API but i get the error "message": "Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into....) from Postman

API Route:

```
Route::post('/posts','PostController@store');
```

The store function in my controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {


        $post= new Post;
        $post->all = $request->all();

        $post->save();

    }
```

Comment: What type of `all` is? It is a database field or you want to set all request fields to model attributes in such a way? If you want set all fields from request - you need `$post->fill($request->all);`

Comment: $post->all is just an attribute (representing a columm) of post. You cannot assign the array from your request to that.

Comment: How could i do that ?

Comment: Why don't you use normal colums for the values?

Comment: But keep in mind that `fillable` property must has an array of fileds that used for mass assignement. For more details please refer https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent - Mass Assignment

Comment: @FreeLightman I just did that but i still get the same error.

Comment: @NikosL24 Can you specify what exactly you did?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, check your `post#all` field type. If it a database field - you can set only data of the same type, for example for string type you can set only php string.

If it is not a filed but you want to set all attributes from request to model, you can do it with `Model::create($request->all())`.

> However, before doing so, you will need to specify either a fillable
>   or guarded attribute on the model, as all Eloquent models protect
>   against mass-assignment by default.

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent) - Mass Assignment

In other words to may define a property in model `fillable` which will be an array and contains fields that will be mass assignable (in your way - fields from request).

It might be better to use `$request->only()` and provide only the data you want to take out of the request, which will reduce the possibility of user errors causing you a problem, as `$request->all()` will include any input data, including the query string.

Comment: @AndrewWillis Does laravel have a method for retrieving only POST data like symfony `$request->request`?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, although blindly using all provided data from the user is not really a wise move, since anybody can add POST data. Anybody can also send JSON content to an API endpoint, so after using validation I find the best approach is to go `$request->only()` and only use the fields I'm expecting from the user.

Comment: @AndrewWillis I agree that filtering data is one more step in security but controller becomes a little messy. Generally I think controller should not know what field a model has. Maybe it will be better to set static `fields` property with changable attrtibutes for model. And then set `fillable` property in model to that `fields`. Then a controller would has `Model::create($request->only(Model::fields));`. How about this?

Comment: @AndrewWillis Or another solution may be taken from symfony. It has an array of fields of form field in one filed. For example if model is Post, form field 'title' will have name `post[title]`. Then a controller would has `Model::create($request->get('post'))`

Comment: The problem with any kind of approach like this is that the Model / Request / Controller all need to know about each other in some way. It's the perfect example of why using Repositories and the Entity / Boundary / Interactor method, where everything gets delegated to the application, which is miles beyond the scope of the question 